# Kendo DatePicker in Durandal Modal popup

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, durandal

I have a Kendo Datepicker that worked perfectly on a div while I was beginning development of a page.

After I got everything all set and working the way it was supposed, I moved the datepicker to a Durandal Modal as was the requirement. The modal works fine, and other databinding is working on the modal, but not the datepicker.

I have tried loading the datepicker at various times in the Durandal lifecycle such as activate, compositionComplete and attached, as well as changing the Z Index to 20000. I am not quite user what I might be missing.

Here is the latest pertinent code:

```js
 define([
     'durandal/app',
     'plugins/router',
     'plugins/dialog',
     'services/datacontext',
     'services/dialogs',
     'viewmodels/helpers/vc',
     'services/logger',
     'services/settings'
 ],
 function (app, router, dialog, datacontext, dialogs, vc, logger, settings) {
  var featureSetToEdit;
  var startFeaturesDatePicker = null;
  var endFeaturesDatePicker = null;
  var today = new Date();
  var featList = ko.observableArray(['']);
  var saving = ko.observable(false);
  var isUserInReadOnlyRole = ko.observable(true);

  function attached() {
     loadDatePickers();
  };

  function compositionComplete() {
     isUserInReadOnlyRole(vc.isUserReadOnly(datacontext.userRole));
  };

  function loadDatePickers() {
     startFeaturesDatePicker = $("#startDateFeatureSet").kendoDatePicker({
        value: today,
        format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy',
        change: setStartDate,
     }).data('kendoDatePicker');
     endFeaturesDatePicker = $("#endDateFeatureSet").kendoDatePicker({
        value: today,
        format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy',
        change: setEndDate,
     }).data('kendoDatePicker');
  };

  var setStartDate = function () {
     startFeaturesDatePicker.value($("#startDateFeatureSet").val());
  };

  var setEndDate = function () {
     endFeaturesDatePicker.value($("#endDateFeatureSet").val());
  };

  function checkboxDivId(featuresKey) {
     return 'checkboxDivId' + featuresKey;
  };

  function edit(featureSetToEdit, fList) {
     self = this;
     self.featList(fList);
     return dialog.show(self);
  };

  function save() {

  };

  function cancel() {
     dialogs.confirmYesNo('Discard changes to this feature Set?', 'Confirm cancel',
        function () {
           dialog.close(self, false);
        },
        function () {
           return;
        }
     );
  };

  // Definition of viewmodel (list of exposed properties and methods)
  var vm = {
     featList: featList,
     edit: edit,
     save: save,
     saving: saving,
     cancel: cancel,
     isUserInReadOnlyRole: isUserInReadOnlyRole,
     checkboxDivId: checkboxDivId
  };
  return vm;
});
```

HTML

```html
<div class="messageBox autoclose" style="min-height: 330px" >
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>Edit Feature Set</h3>

</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; background-color: #ddd; min-height: 250px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid silver;">
  <table class="k-grid">
     <tr class="dataRow" style="padding: 2px;">
        <td><span>Start Date</span></td>
        <td><input id="startDateFeatureSet" style="width:150px;" class="highZIndex" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="dataRow" style="padding: 2px;">
        <td><span>End Date</span></td>
        <td><input id="endDateFeatureSet" style="width:150px;" class="highZIndex" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="dataRow" style="padding: 2px;">
        <td><span>Features</span></td>
        <td id="featuresCheckbox" style="font-size: 10pt; text-align: left" data-bind="foreach: featList">
           <input data-bind="attr: { id: $parent.checkboxDivId($data.keyChar), value: $data.keyChar }" type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom:6px;" />&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: $data.name" style="margin-top:6px;"></span> <br />
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>


</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div style="float: right">
     <span class="icon-spin icon-spinner waiting" data-bind="visible: saving">  </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save, enable: !saving() && !isUserInReadOnlyRole()">Save</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: cancel, enable: !saving()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you please take a look and let me know what I might be missing?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but I don't have any problems with this when using knockout-kendo library.    My assumption would be that it should work if calling from compositionComplete()

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would have thought...I did just try it again just in case...but no luck :(  Thanks so much for trying! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after finding I still needed to load it through the usual Kendo initialization, I searched more until I found that to load it properly I needed the following code in the modal js page:

```
self = this;
self.compositionComplete = function () {
    loadDatePickers();
};

return dialog.show(self);
```

Now it works exactly the same as a datepicker on a non-modal page.
I hope this helps others to!

Comment: have you tried the knockout-kendo library?  You really ought to be using custom bindings for this sort of business.

Comment: I have not tried it, I'll take a look. Thanks for the suggestion!